# How load data before any component initialized in Blazor Web Assembly

Tags: blazor

I need to load some data from api before any component is initialized. I tried to load them in OnInitializedAsync() method in MainLayout unfortunaly before they load components are already initialized without those data.

Answer (score 2):

Two further options that ensure the data is loaded before any rendering event occurs.

### Load the data at Startup

`Program` for the WASM project:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Get the service instance
var myService = app.Services.GetService<MyService>();

// make sure we get the data before loading the rest of the app
if (myService is not null)
    await myService.GetData();

/....
```

I use this approach to load test data into an InMemory database.

#### Override SetParametersAsync

Follow the inline comments explicitly.

```cs
@page "/"
@inject MyService Service
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
    public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        // Set the component parameters
        // Absolute must to do first
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        // Await on the data load
        await Service.GetData();

        // Now do the normal Lifecycle componenty stuff
        // Pass an empty ParameterView as we've already set them
        await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your components/information related to your data with `@if(dataLoaded){ }`. This way nothing will be rendered until `dataLoaded` is at `true`.

`dataLoaded` can obviously be replaced by, for example, checking if a value is `null` or a list is empty.